# If we assume $a=0$ if $a\mathrm{p(x)} =0$, can we also assume $\mathrm{p(x)} \neq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be a trivial question, given the following equation

$$a\cdot \mathrm{p(x)} = 0$$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{p(x)}$ is a polynomial with $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then either $a=0$ or $\mathrm{p(x)}=0$.

Just for the sake of asking the question, if we assume $a=0$, do we also suppose $\mathrm{p(x)} \neq 0$ or is that something that may or may not be deduced from the assumption $a=0$?

Comment: If $a\cdot p(x)=0$, then $a=0$ or $p(x)=0$ or both are equal to $0$.

Comment: $a\cdot p(x)=0\leftrightarrow a=0\lor p(x)=0

Comment: Well, what *if* p(x) = $x^2$.  Then $0*p(x) =$.  0 times *anything* is zero so if $a = 0$ then $p(x)$ can be any dang thing it wants so, no.  For $a*p(x) = 0; a=0$ absolutely *NOTHING* can be deduced about $p(x)$.

Comment: Suppose $p(x) = 0$.  That *can* sometimes happen can't it?  Supposes $a = 0$.  That can happen too, can't it. Then $a*p(x) = 0$.  Can we conclude $p(x) \ne 0$.  No, because it doesn't. Now suppose $p(x) \ne 0$.  That also can happen.  And if $a=0$.  Then $a*p(x) = 0$.  Can we conclude $p(x) = 0$.  No, because it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

If a = 0, p(x) can be either zero or non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your case $a \cdot p(x) = 0 $

Then $a = 0$ or $p(x) = 0$

Or  both of them are equal to zero

Other case if - for example - your equation comes like this

$a + i \cdot p(x) = 0$

Then both of them must equal to zero at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Since $0*anything = 0$ what can we deduce about *something* if $0*something = 0$.  Well, we can deduce it could be *anything*.

(Okay, I didn't intend to make that joke... but it's true and for the exact same reason the joke works.)